# How to disconnect inactive users in an application chat xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I'm trying to find an approach to disconnect an active user for an application chat when the application is in the background for more than 120 second, however the timer seems that it's not working on the background here it's the code

```
   func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { (timer) in
            print("start the logout code")
        }
    }
```

in the code you can see 3 seconds, because even 3 seconds it's not working. Can you please provide me what is the best approach that i can use so i logout the user and not keep showing him in the online list?

Comment: You cannot do anything when you are in the background, you are suspended. If you want to logout the user because the user is in the background, logout the user when the user goes into the background.

Comment: @matt doesnt make sense so if the user go to background by mistake i logout him? doesn't make sense like that

Comment: I understand that, I'm just trying to give a sense of reality. There is no such thing as doing somethat 120 seconds after the user goes into the background. That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a chat application my self, and I had this problem that took me a long time to figure out a workaround for it.

What I have noticed is that background won't give me a long time to logout the user, so I decided whenver the user or the application enter in:

1. `sceneDidDisconnect`

In this case I will call a function that will put the user offline.

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            print("put offline")
            user.logout()
}
```

2. `sceneDidBecomeActive`

In this case I will call a function that will put the user back online again.

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            user.offline()
}
```

3. `applicationWillTerminate`

When the application is terminated, I call a function that will put the user `Offline` then `Logout` the user and finally `Delete the user` from database.

I hope this technique will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The background work is very limited, we cannot do this kind of calculations with a 100% probability that they will be executed. This logic is best left to the backend